# GAE - Sharing Authentication Across Apps

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, openid

Let's say I had a root app and multiple sub-apps. Would it be possible to share authenticated sessions across them?

I'm using Google App Engine (Python).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sub-app? If it's running at a different path under the same application (and same hostname), it can share authentication.

Comment: I mean different applications on separate sub-domains.

Comment: just be careful about not violating the TOS.  if you plan is to have a ton of tiny instances of your app that all fall under the free quota, you need to read the Terms of Service very carefully, as I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: I was worried about that. Each app would be completely different in functionality, it would just bear the same 'brand' name'. I don't want to push my luck though. :P

Answer (score 4):

If you use [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/), the wonderful lightweight almost-not-a-framework that @moraes developed specifically for App Engine use, you get many excellent choices for authentication approaches (see [here](http://www.tipfy.org/docs/api/tipfy.ext.auth.html)) several of which will let you achieve what you're after.

Comment: Checkout a demo website which is work in progress
http://tipfy-auth.appspot.com/

thanks @moraes ;-)

Comment: Would I have to use the whole framework? I need a solution that can integrate with my current code.

Comment: @Matt, tipfy's "whole framework" is _tiny_, as well as totally modular and WSGI-centric -- I can't think of anything that might be easier to integrate with _whatever_ framework you're currently using (you chose not to even **mention** that framework in your Q and tags, btw, so, how did you expect anybody in the world to mystically guess that you attached any importance whatsoever to that framework, whatever it may actually be?!-).

Answer (score 1):

Not using the built in authentication support - users have to authenticate separately with each application.

Comment: So any ideas on how I could implement this? How easy is manual authentication in Python?

Maybe I could use something like OpenID on my root application and the sub apps could make a request to this app to find out if the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Matt H Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277884/openid-authentication-on-appengine-and-non-appengine-subdomains/3280333#3280333

Comment: You'd need to set cross-subdomain cookies for sessions (easy), or use a single sign-on mechanism (a bit more complex).